# Python openpyxl reads float value incorrectly

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

There is a cell in my Excel worksheet which contains the exact numeric value **708.143**.

It is formatted as a number with 2 decimal places.

It is displayed as **708.14**.

When I read this value in Python via the openpyxl library, the value retrieved is **708.1429999999998**.

How do I retrieve the raw data value of **708.143**?

This is a simplified representation of my code:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, read_only = False, data_only = True)
ws = wb['blah']
range = ws['BS2' : 'BS289']
cell = range[20][0]
actual_value = cell.value # = 708.1429999999998
expected_value              = 708.143
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Most likely your first sentence is not quite accurate... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel

Comment: Apply rounding manually.

Comment: Perhaps the round() function could help, especially if you don't need varying levels of precision.

Comment: For those saying use the round() function: How would you know how many places to round if the value was sometimes 708.143 here and 708.1434 someplace else?